# Upload file via @aws-sdk/client-s3 and graphql-upload

Tags: amazon-s3, graphql, nestjs

**S3('@aws-sdk/client-s3') upload function**

**import { Upload } from '@aws-sdk/lib-storage';**

```
async s3UploadPhoto(fileStream, name, mimetype) {
 const fileKey = this.getFileKey(name);

 const sendParams: PutObjectCommandInput = {
   Bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET_NAME,
   Body: fileStream,
   Key: fileKey,
   ContentType: mimetype,
 };
 try {
  const parallelUploads3 = new Upload({
    client: this.s3,
    tags: [],
    queueSize: 4, 
    leavePartsOnError: false,
    params: sendParams,
  });

  parallelUploads3.on('httpUploadProgress', (progress) => {
    console.log(progress);
  });

  return parallelUploads3.done();

 } catch (e) {
  throw new BadRequestException('');
 }
}
```

**And Graphql upload code via** 'graphql-upload'

```
 const fileStream = file.createReadStream();

  await this.s3Service.s3UploadPhoto(
    fileStream,
    file.filename,
    file.mimetype,
  );
```

I get error: **ReferenceError: ReadableStream is not defined**

If uploads a file to s3 without lib-storage, I get error: **Are you using a Stream of unknown length as the Body of a PutObject request? Consider using Upload instead from @aws-sdk/lib-storage.**

What is wrong written that I get error **"ReadableStream is not defined"**?

Comment: Did you get an answer to it @Nikita

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import { ReadStream } from 'fs';

export const loadStream = (stream: ReadStream): Promise<Buffer> =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const chunks = [];
    stream.on('data', (chunk) => chunks.push(chunk));
    stream.on('error', reject);
    stream.on('end', () => resolve(Buffer.concat(chunks)));
  });



async uploadPhoto(fileStream,.....) {
    const file = await loadStream(fileStream);

    const sendParams: PutObjectCommandInput = {
      Bucket: 'second-phone-photos',
      Body: file,
      Key: fileKey,
      ACL: 'public-read',
      ContentType: mimetype,
    };
}

const fileStream = photo.createReadStream();

await uploadPhoto(fileStream, ....)
```